# Keep leading zeros when joining data sources in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a data source in Tableau (10.0) where I am joining a table from SQL  with an Excel file. The join happens on a `site id` but when reading the id from the excel source, Tableau strips the leading zeros (and SQL keeps leading zeros). I see [this example](https://www.interworks.com/blog/skennedy/2014/05/05/how-handle-headache-leading-zeros-tableau)
to add the leading zeros back as a new, calculated field. But the join is still dropping rows because the id is not properly formatted when making the join.

How do I get the excel data source to read the column with the leading zeros so I can do the join?

Comment: You have to be very careful with excel as a source, it is sometimes too clever for anyone's wellbeing. Excel often auto-converts strings that look like numbers into actual numbers in its internal format. It does the by default when opening CSV files unless you tell it not to.

Answer (score 1):

1. Launch Excel and choose to open a new blank workbook.
2. Click the Data tab and select From Text.
3. Browse to the saved CSV file and select Import.
4. Ensure that Delimited is selected and click Next.
5. Leave Tab as the delimiter and click Next.
6. Select the column containing the data with leading zeros and click
   Text.
7. Repeat for each column which contains leading zeros.
8. Click Finish.
9. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of or used tableau, but it sounds as though something (jet/ace database driver being used to read excel file?) is determining the column to be numeric and parsing the data as numbers, losing leading zeroes

If your attempts at putting them back are giving you grief, I'd recommend trying the other direction instead; get sqlserver to convert its strings to numbers. Number matching should be more reliable than String matching, so long as the two systems don't handle rounding differently :)

Answer (score 0):

If your Excel file was read in from a CSV and the Site ID is showing "Number Stored as Text", I think you can solve your problem by telling Tableau on the Data Source entry that the field is actually a string. On the preview data source view, change the "#" (designating number) to string so that both the SQL source and the Excel source are both strings before doing the join.

Answer (score 0):

This typically has to do with the way Excel stores values as mentioned above.  I would play around with the number formatting for the Site ID column in Excel itself, not Tableau, and changed that two "Text" in Excel.   You can verify if Tableau will read it properly with the leading 0s by exporting your excel file to csv and looking in the csv files to see if the leading 0s are still there.